# What is the most efficient way to create an order count summary by hour, day, month in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, report

Given a table:

```
create table #orders (
    orderid int,
    orderdatetime datetime
)
```

What is the best way to write sql to output a report containing the count of orders from the current and previous 24 hours, total orders for the current day and previous 7 days, total orders for the current week and previous 4 weeks, and total orders for the month and previous 6 months?

I'm wondering if this can be efficiently rolled up into a single sql using analytical functions, or if 4 sql statements generating the 4 groups of data is the only (or best) way.

Also, given the hourly/day/week grouping, how would one do that in sql server?  Datetimes seem to be a pain in the ass everytime I have to do something like this with them...

Ideas?  Put into a SSAS cube and do it from there maybe?

Comment: Output as one row or multiple rows?

Comment: @Peter question answered already - it's not exactly what I need - but I can get the grouping and filtering I need from that.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  DATEPART(month, orderdatetime), DATEPART(week, orderdatetime), DATEPART(day, orderdatetime), COUNT(*)
FROM    #orders
GROUP BY
        DATEPART(month, orderdatetime), DATEPART(week, orderdatetime), DATEPART(day, orderdatetime) WITH ROLLUP
```

This will group the `COUNT`'s by day, week and month in a single query.

The week rollups will have a `NULL` in `DATEPART(day, orderdatetime)` column, the month rollups will have a `NULL` in both `DATEPART(day, orderdatetime)` and `DATEPART(week, orderdatetime)` columns.

To make it for every hour, day, week or month from the current without gaps, use `CTE`'s:

```
WITH    q_hours AS
        (
        SELECT  0 AS col_hour
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  col_hour + 1
        FROM    q_hours
        WHERE   col_hour < 22
        ),
        q_days AS
        (
        SELECT  0 AS col_day
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  col_day + 1
        FROM    q_days
        WHERE   col_day < 31
        ),
        q_months AS
        (
        SELECT  0 AS col_month
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  col_month + 1
        FROM    q_months
        WHERE   col_month < 12
        )
SELECT  col_month, col_day, col_hour, COUNT(orderid)
FROM    q_hours
CROSS JOIN
        q_days
CROSS JOIN
        q_months
LEFT JOIN
        #orders
ON      DATEDIFF(month, orderdatetime, GETDATE()) = col_month
        AND DATEDIFF(day, orderdatetime, GETDATE()) % 31 = col_day
        AND DATEDIFF(hour, orderdatetime, GETDATE()) % 24 = col_hour
GROUP BY
        col_month, col_day, col_hour WITH ROLLUP
HAVING  (
        col_month = 0
        AND col_day = 0
        AND col_hour IS NOT NULL
        ) -- all hours within 24 hours from now
        OR
        (
        col_month = 0
        AND col_day <= 7
        AND col_hour IS NULL
        ) -- all days within 7 days from now
        OR
        (
        col_month <= 6
        AND col_day IS NULL
        AND col_hour IS NULL
        ) -- all months within 6 months from now
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to make it always have every hour, aside from making an hour of day table and joining to that?

Comment: The question specified that there are different ranges for each date part - this query will only give you the counts of all of them for a single range.

Comment: Perfect edit.  This was exactly what I was working on.  Was almost done when you posted it.  Faster next time please.  LOL ;)

Comment: your with clause is littered with copy/paste bugs

Comment: Actually, the whole solution just doesn't work because the count(*) counts empty hours as 1 and disregards any order data at all.

Comment: you have confused yourself.  you're referring to day as both days ago and day of the month.  ditto with all the others...

Comment: The currently implemented solution uses ONLY the hours, days and months from now. I left the CTE's as is to make easier to change the HAVING conditions whenever the need arises.

Comment: This solution doesn't work.  It won't count anything > 1 day because col_hour is > 24 in that case.  :(  SOOOOO close....  grr...

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi: try now. It would be much easier if you posted some sample data so that I could test before answering.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the four selects from a "dummy table" or an "identity" table that consists of a single row.

You could have:

```
SELECT
    (<query count of orders current/prev 24 hours>) as <name1>,
    (<total orders current + 7 days>) as <name2>,
    (<total orders current week + 4 weeks>) as <name3>,
    (<total orders month + 6 months>) as <name4>
FROM
<IDENTITY table>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want different timeframes for each datepart type, using a single query with rollup probably won't give you what you want.  I'd consider just unioning them all together similar to something like this...

```
SELECT  DatePartValue = DATEPART(HH, orderdatetime), 
        Type = 'Hourly',
        COUNT(*)
FROM    #orders
WHERE   orderdatetime > DATEADD(HH, -25, GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH, orderdatetime)
UNION 
SELECT  DATEPART(DD, orderdatetime), 
        Type = 'Daily',
        COUNT(*)
FROM    #orders
WHERE   orderdatetime > DATEADD(DD, -8, GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATEPART(DD, orderdatetime)
UNION 
SELECT  DATEPART(WEEK, orderdatetime), 
        Type = 'Weekly',
        COUNT(*)
FROM    #orders
WHERE   orderdatetime > DATEADD(WEEK, -5, GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, orderdatetime)
ORDER BY Type, DatePartValue
UNION 
SELECT  DATEPART(MM, orderdatetime), 
        Type = 'Monthly',
        COUNT(*)
FROM    #orders
WHERE   orderdatetime > DATEADD(MM, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATEPART(MM, orderdatetime)
ORDER BY Type, DatePartValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want grouping sets. I've understand that sql server supports grouping sets.

**EDIT1:** I've read that sql server 2005 doesn't support grouping sets but sql server 2008 does. Here an interesting read on a presumed but not existing difference between mapreduce and an rdbms like Oracle and Sql Server. Please read the comments too!! http://www.data-miners.com/blog/2008/01/mapreduce-and-sql-aggregations.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     
    sum(case when orderdatetime between GetDate() - 1 and GetDate() then 1 else 0 end) as Current24Hours,
    sum(case when orderdatetime between GetDate() - 2 and GetDate() - 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Previous24Hours,
    sum(case when orderdatetime between GetDate() - 7 and GetDate() then 1 else 0 end) as Current7Days,
    sum(case when orderdatetime between GetDate() - 14 and GetDate() - 7 then 1 else 0 end) as Previous7Days,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF (m, OrderDate, @now) <= 1 then 1 else 0 end) as PreviousMonth,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF (m, OrderDate, @now) <= 6 then 1 else 0 end) as PreviousSixMonths
FROM orders
```

Answer (score 0):

For results in one row, something like this:

```
select
  orders_day   = sum(case when datediff(hour,orderdatetime,getdate())  < 24 then 1 else 0 end)
, orders_week  = sum(case when datediff(day,orderdatetime,getdate())   < 7  then 1 else 0 end)
, orders_month = sum(case when datediff(week,orderdatetime,getdate())  < 4  then 1 else 0 end)
, orders_half  = sum(case when datediff(month,orderdatetime,getdate()) < 6  then 1 else 0 end)
from #orders
```

You may want to fine tune the date criteria to get appropriate behavior.

For multiple rows, take the results above and transpose it with UNPIVOT or CASE .. CROSS JOIN.